# how to check session with particular id is expired or not in php?

Tags: php, session

I am making chat site.Session will start for each user with any randomly generated string as session id ,when user open site and session id will be stored in database.I want to check whether session with particular session id is expired or not..

I have done everthing from my site but not get any solution,can anyone have solution??

i check following code

```
 $data="select * from users";
$record=mysql_query($data);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($record))
{
    $var=$row['id'];
if(!(isset($_SESSION[$var])))
{
$del="DELETE from users where id='$var'";
mysql_query($del);
}
```

?>

Comment: _Session will start for each user with any randomly generated string as session id_ And what is that _randomly generated string_

Comment: i am using mt_rand() function for that

Comment: And what is `$row['id'];`

Comment: $row['id']  is session id in database